# Galina Avanesova: Не могу зайти ни в Мету, ни "к себе". Как быть?

Tags: discussion

Ну как мне войти-то? Заскучамши мы... На комменты право не заработано, увы.

Мучаюсь в поисках слов, чтобы адекватно выразить сострадание, говоря грубее, эмпатию к себе.

Comment: Отметил Ваше сообщение тревогой для модератора. Надеюсь, Вам помогут.

Comment: Мерси боку, Иванушка!

Comment: А кто вошел в ваш старый аккаунт приблизительно в 2:10 Москвы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте восстановить пароль: https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery.

Если не получится, свяжитесь с администрацией: https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/contact.

Comment: Аэрчик, спасибо. При попытке восстановить пароль оказываюсь на том же месте в тот же час, т. е. здесь. Пробую администрацию, но оне все там небось по-аглицки глаголят, я так не играю...

Comment: @ГалинаАванесова пишите по-русски :)

Answer (score 1):

Вам бы для начала надо внятно изложить ситуацию.

1. Почему не можете войти, что отвечает система?
2. Что именно происходит при попытке восстановления пароля. Ответ на почту приходит?

Администрация тут, если не считать модераторов, это в первую голову - Николай Чебановский. Он по-русски, как вы понимаете, говорит, другое дело, что не склонен отвечать на каждый чих пользователя. Но если дело дойдет до критической точки, могу написать о вашей проблеме ему напрямую, как-то раз я это делал, давно, правда. Если, конечно, его адрес не потерял. Но для этого нужны как минимум четкие ответы на вышеобозначенные вопросы.

(+)

> При попытке восстановить пароль оказываюсь на том же месте в тот же
> час, т. е. здесь

Вы надеюсь, понимаете, что восстанавливать пароль от старого аккаунта надо только после выхода из нового? И при этом восстанавливать на ту почту, которая была привязана к старому аккаунту? Ваше лирическое описание заставляет думать, что вы, возможно, каких-то самоочевидных правил не соблюдаете.